# Sorting 2 Integer array list in alternating while descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Im trying to combine 2 arrays into in alternating order and sorted imagine a pyramid with alternating colors(you can't have the same color it has to interchange) and the value inside is the width.

**Example**

```
WhiteA{18,16,11,4,3,2}
BlackB{13,8,6}
```

**Output should be**

```
{18,13,11,8,4}
```

16 was skipped because 16>13 so the next is 11 and 6 was omitted because the the last one would have a double color

```java
for (int i = 0; i < positive.size(); i++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < negative.size(); n++) {

        if (positive.get(i) > Math.abs(negative.get(n))) {
            count.add(positive.get(i));
            if (positive.get(i) < Math.abs(negative.get(n))) {
                count.add(negative.get(n));

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Positive just means white
Negative just means black

I expect the output should be `{18,13,11,8,4}` but when i try my code i get `{18,18,18,16,16,16,11,11}`

Comment: You have a nested for loop: You are iterating once over your second array for each index of your first array, hence the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int ai = 0;
int bi = 0;
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(18,16,11,4,3,2); // this is your first list
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(13,8,6); // this is your second list
List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>();
while (ai < a.size() && bi < b.size()) {
    int current = a.get(ai);
    count.add(current);
    while (bi < b.size() && b.get(bi) > current) {
        ++bi;
    }
    if (bi == b.size()) {
        break;
    }
    current = b.get(bi);
    count.add(current);
    while (ai < a.size() && a.get(ai) > current) {
        ++ai;
    }
    if (ai == a.size()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd try changing your loop type and alternating which array you check through a switch (e.g. i % 2), comparing the first element of the positive/negative array against the last element in the count array.

After comparing: add the value to the count array if it is lower, and then remove the element from the positive/negative array.

Sorry: I'm not at a computer to test it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with how you're using nested loops, inside the negative loop you're always comparing it to the same value of the positive loop, it doesn't increment until after the negative loop has run through all elements, thus the repeated numbers.

Additionally the check if positive is less than negative occurs inside the check that positive is greater than negative, so it'll never trigger.

It's been a while since I've worked with java and I don't have the tools to test it in that environment but here's some code which seems to do the trick in python:

```py
count = []

positive = [18, 16, 11, 4, 3, 2]
negative = [13, 10, 6]

lastGrabPos = False

positiveIndex = 0
negativeIndex = 0

while positiveIndex < len(positive) and negativeIndex < len(negative):
    if positive[positiveIndex] > negative[negativeIndex]:
        if not lastGrabPos:
            count.append(positive[positiveIndex])
            lastGrabPos = True

        positiveIndex += 1


    if positive[positiveIndex] < negative[negativeIndex]:
        if lastGrabPos:
            count.append(negative[negativeIndex])
            lastGrabPos = False
        negativeIndex += 1

if not lastGrabPos:
    count.append(positive[positiveIndex])

else:
    count.append(negative[negativeIndex])
```

Translated to java I believe is...

```java
int positiveIndex = 0;
int negativeIndex = 0;

Boolean lastGrabPos = false;

while(positiveIndex < positive.size() && negativeIndex < negative.size()) {
    if (positive.get(positiveIndex) > Math.abs(negative.get(negativeIndex))){
        if(!lastGrabPos){
            count.add(positive.get(positiveIndex));
            lastGrabPos = true;
        }
        positiveIndex += 1;
    }

    if (positive.get(positiveIndex) < Math.abs(negative.get(negativeIndex))){
        if(lastGrabPos){
            count.add(negative.get(negativeIndex));
            lastGrabPos = false;
        }
        negativeIndex += 1;
    }

}

if(!lastGrabPos){
    count.add(positive.get(positiveIndex));
}
else{
    count.add(negative.get(negativeIndex));
}

for(Integer element : count) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3719)
 at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3688)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:237)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:242)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:467)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:480)

Comment: A heap error??? Idk like I said my java is rusty, try making the  '>' into '>=' on the line 'if (positive.get(positiveIndex) > Math.abs(negative.get(negativeIndex))){'

All I can say for sure is that the python seems to hold of correct, so the logic should all be there

Comment: trying to debug it but yeah if its correct in python it should be correct here too lol

Comment: @lorenzo you were right, found the bug and fixed it let me know if that works